# how can i restrict my module to use single url

Tags: magento-1.9, module

Right now i am facing a problem. i have requirement to use a single url like `test.html` or `test` at one time. right now problem is that `test` is always true because it is module name. right now i  want if the use add the `url suffix` then  url `test.html` is active otherwise `test`. no direct access with `test` allowed. any help or any suggestion is welcome.
 i am using this code

**Router.php**

```
         $urlsuffix = Mage::helper('test')->getUrlSuffix(); 
         $identifier = trim($request->getPathInfo(), '/'); 

        if($urlsuffix!="")
        { 
              $pos = strpos($identifier,$urlsuffix);
        }else {
             $pos=true;
        }  
        if($identifier=='test' && $pos== true)
        {
            $request->setModuleName('test')
                ->setControllerName('index')
                ->setActionName('index');

        return true;

        }
```

Comment: I think custom Router will your friend to solve this issue

Comment: @KeyurShah already using the custom router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figure out myself adding condition in `controller` `preDispatch()` function work for me.

```
public function preDispatch()
    {
   parent::preDispatch();
   $urlsuffix = Mage::helper('test')->getUrlSuffix(); 
   $identifier = trim($this->getRequest()->getPathInfo(), '/');
    if($urlsuffix!="" and strpos($identifier,$urlsuffix)==false)
       { 
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError(Mage::helper('partners')->__('Sorry This Feature is disabled temporarily'));
                $this->norouteAction();
       }
    }
```